# Excel columns mapping with data fields in c#

Tags: c#, database, excel

I am inserting an Excel sheet into a database. In that I displayed Excel sheet column names in text boxes. Here I needed mapping user selected columns of database table to the Excel sheet columns.

How to map these??

I mean  user selects field name for sheet and columns from dropdown list.

My code:

```
private void cmbBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (cmbBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            cmbBox1.DataSource = dt;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read excel file first which could be done by using **oledb**, This code project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB) shows you how to do it. You can also use **excel interop** or **open xml** to read excel files.

You can not read *images* using oledb, but excel interop and open xml will let you do it. This [excel interop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9992/Faster-MS-Excel-Reading-using-Office-Interop-Assem) and [open xml](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML) article will help you on the way.

Comment: i read excel file and inserting also.but my requirement is user has to be data field choosable.., now it inserts as which order excel columns have.

Comment: You can read the columns of excel file from first row and ask user for his/her choice columns

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the OledbConnection to connect to Excel.

The following article will help you

- [Import Data from Excel to SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32581/Import-Data-from-Excel-to-SQL-Server)